# “wget ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs” failing on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ssl, openssl, wget

Ubuntu 14.04's default wget cannot handle SSL. How can I fix this? I **do not** want to use --no-certificate-check.

The certificate I want to authenticate is authenticated against the Root CA from Thawte.

Comment: What message does it fail with? Is there any authentication or session management required on the source site?

Answer (score 1):

The filenames in the CA directory are not free-form. Each file is for one single CA certificate and the name of the file must be identical to the `<hash_value>.<n>` based of the subject name 
 i.e. `<hash_value>` is the value returned by:

```
 openssl x509 -subject_hash -in cafile.cert
```

and `<n>`  n is an integer, typically `0`. If the hash value already exists then n will be incremented.

Normally I would set up the directory with a descriptive filename for actual CA files i.e. thawte.ca.cert and the hash value as a symlink to that file. The openssl `c_rehash` utility will set up those those symlinks for you.

Comment: Very Interesting. Could you give a step-by-step for Linux CLI?

Comment: As download each of the [root certificates](http://www.thawte.com/roots/), run the above command and create a symbolic link????  Oh well, since I'm bored...  `wget http://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem ; openssl x509 -in thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem -noout -subject_hash ; ln -s thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem 2e4eed3c.0`  BTW the hash value differs between openssl above and below versions 1.0 ...